# Find how many days it takes for a value to double in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I'm making a table with the latest number cases of coronavirus in JavaScript, and I am at a point where I want to create a column that shows how many days it took for the number of confirmCases to double. Here is an example:

```
{
  "message": "Success",
  "source": "JHU CSSE",
  "sourceURL": "https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/2019-nCoV",
  "updateDate": "2020-03-22T11:08:41.651Z",
  "data": {
    "3/15/20": {
      "Afghanistan": 16,
      "Albania": 42,
      "Algeria": 48,
      "Andorra": 1,
      "Angola": 0,
      "Antigua and Barbuda": 1,
      "Argentina": 45,
      "Armenia": 26,
      "Australia": 297,
      "Austria": 860,
      "Azerbaijan": 23,
      "Bahamas, The": 0,
      "Bahrain": 214,
      "Bangladesh": 5,
      "Barbados": 0,
      "Belarus": 27,
      "Belgium": 886,
      "Benin": 0,
      "Bhutan": 1,
      "Bolivia": 10,
      "Bosnia and Herzegovina": 24,
      "Brazil": 162,
      "Brunei": 50,
      "Bulgaria": 51,
      "Burkina Faso": 3,
      "Cabo Verde": 0,
      "Cambodia": 7,
      "Cameroon": 2,
      "Canada": 252,
      "Cape Verde": 0,
      "Central African Republic": 1,
      "Chad": 0,
      "Chile": 74,
      "China": 81003,
      "Colombia": 34,
      "Congo (Brazzaville)": 1,
      "Congo (Kinshasa)": 2,
      "Costa Rica": 27,
      "Cote d'Ivoire": 1,
      "Croatia": 49,
      "Cruise Ship": 696,
      "Cuba": 4,
      "Cyprus": 26,
      "Czechia": 253,
      "Denmark": 875,
      "Djibouti": 0,
      "Dominican Republic": 11,
      "East Timor": 0,
      "Ecuador": 28,
      "Egypt": 110,
      "El Salvador": 0,
      "Equatorial Guinea": 1,
      "Eritrea": 0,
      "Estonia": 171,
      "Eswatini": 1,
      "Ethiopia": 1,
      "Fiji": 0,
      "Finland": 244,
      "France": 4523,
      "Gabon": 1,
      "Gambia, The": 0,
      "Georgia": 33,
      "Germany": 5795,
      "Ghana": 6,
      "Greece": 331,
      "Guatemala": 1,
      "Guinea": 1,
      "Guyana": 4,
      "Haiti": 0,
      "Holy See": 1,
      "Honduras": 3,
      "Hungary": 32,
      "Iceland": 171,
      "India": 113,
      "Indonesia": 117,
      "Iran": 13938,
      "Iraq": 116,
      "Ireland": 129,
      "Israel": 251,
      "Italy": 24747,
      "Jamaica": 10,
      "Japan": 839,
      "Jordan": 8,
      "Kazakhstan": 9,
      "Kenya": 3,
      "Korea, South": 8162,
      "Kosovo": 2,
      "Kuwait": 112,
      "Kyrgyzstan": 0,
      "Latvia": 30,
      "Lebanon": 110,
      "Liberia": 0,
      "Liechtenstein": 4,
      "Lithuania": 12,
      "Luxembourg": 59,
      "Madagascar": 0,
      "Malaysia": 428,
      "Maldives": 13,
      "Malta": 21,
      "Martinique": 9,
      "Mauritania": 1,
      "Mauritius": 0,
      "Mexico": 41,
      "Moldova": 23,
      "Monaco": 2,
      "Mongolia": 1,
      "Montenegro": 0,
      "Morocco": 28,
      "Namibia": 2,
      "Nepal": 1,
      "Netherlands": 1138,
      "New Zealand": 8,
      "Nicaragua": 0,
      "Niger": 0,
      "Nigeria": 2,
      "North Macedonia": 14,
      "Norway": 1221,
      "Oman": 22,
      "Pakistan": 53,
      "Panama": 43,
      "Papua New Guinea": 0,
      "Paraguay": 6,
      "Peru": 43,
      "Philippines": 140,
      "Poland": 119,
      "Portugal": 245,
      "Qatar": 401,
      "Romania": 131,
      "Russia": 63,
      "Rwanda": 1,
      "Saint Lucia": 2,
      "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines": 1,
      "San Marino": 101,
      "Saudi Arabia": 103,
      "Senegal": 24,
      "Serbia": 48,
      "Seychelles": 2,
      "Singapore": 226,
      "Slovakia": 54,
      "Slovenia": 219,
      "Somalia": 0,
      "South Africa": 51,
      "Spain": 7798,
      "Sri Lanka": 18,
      "Sudan": 1,
      "Suriname": 1,
      "Sweden": 1022,
      "Switzerland": 2200,
      "Taiwan*": 59,
      "Tanzania": 0,
      "Thailand": 114,
      "Togo": 1,
      "Trinidad and Tobago": 2,
      "Tunisia": 18,
      "Turkey": 6,
      "US": 3499,
      "Uganda": 0,
      "Ukraine": 3,
      "United Arab Emirates": 98,
      "United Kingdom": 1145,
      "Uruguay": 4,
      "Uzbekistan": 1,
      "Venezuela": 10,
      "Vietnam": 56,
      "Zambia": 0,
      "Zimbabwe": 0
    },
    "3/16/20": {
      "Afghanistan": 21,
      "Albania": 51,
      "Algeria": 54,
      "Andorra": 2,
      "Angola": 0,
      "Antigua and Barbuda": 1,
      "Argentina": 56,
      "Armenia": 52,
      "Australia": 377,
      "Austria": 1018,
      "Azerbaijan": 15,
      "Bahamas, The": 1,
      "Bahrain": 214,
      "Bangladesh": 8,
      "Barbados": 0,
      "Belarus": 36,
      "Belgium": 1058,
      "Benin": 1,
      "Bhutan": 1,
      "Bolivia": 11,
      "Bosnia and Herzegovina": 25,
      "Brazil": 200,
      "Brunei": 54,
      "Bulgaria": 52,
      "Burkina Faso": 15,
      "Cabo Verde": 0,
      "Cambodia": 7,
      "Cameroon": 4,
      "Canada": 415,
      "Cape Verde": 0,
      "Central African Republic": 1,
      "Chad": 0,
      "Chile": 155,
      "China": 81033,
      "Colombia": 54,
      "Congo (Brazzaville)": 1,
      "Congo (Kinshasa)": 2,
      "Costa Rica": 35,
      "Cote d'Ivoire": 1,
      "Croatia": 57,
      "Cruise Ship": 696,
      "Cuba": 4,
      "Cyprus": 33,
      "Czechia": 298,
      "Denmark": 933,
      "Djibouti": 0,
      "Dominican Republic": 11,
      "East Timor": 0,
      "Ecuador": 37,
      "Egypt": 150,
      "El Salvador": 0,
      "Equatorial Guinea": 1,
      "Eritrea": 0,
      "Estonia": 205,
      "Eswatini": 1,
      "Ethiopia": 5,
      "Fiji": 0,
      "Finland": 277,
      "France": 6668,
      "Gabon": 1,
      "Gambia, The": 0,
      "Georgia": 33,
      "Germany": 7272,
      "Ghana": 6,
      "Greece": 331,
      "Guatemala": 2,
      "Guinea": 1,
      "Guyana": 4,
      "Haiti": 0,
      "Holy See": 1,
      "Honduras": 6,
      "Hungary": 39,
      "Iceland": 180,
      "India": 119,
      "Indonesia": 134,
      "Iran": 14991,
      "Iraq": 124,
      "Ireland": 169,
      "Israel": 255,
      "Italy": 27980,
      "Jamaica": 10,
      "Japan": 825,
      "Jordan": 17,
      "Kazakhstan": 10,
      "Kenya": 3,
      "Korea, South": 8236,
      "Kosovo": 2,
      "Kuwait": 123,
      "Kyrgyzstan": 0,
      "Latvia": 34,
      "Lebanon": 99,
      "Liberia": 1,
      "Liechtenstein": 4,
      "Lithuania": 17,
      "Luxembourg": 77,
      "Madagascar": 0,
      "Malaysia": 566,
      "Maldives": 13,
      "Malta": 30,
      "Martinique": 15,
      "Mauritania": 1,
      "Mauritius": 0,
      "Mexico": 53,
      "Moldova": 23,
      "Monaco": 7,
      "Mongolia": 1,
      "Montenegro": 0,
      "Morocco": 29,
      "Namibia": 2,
      "Nepal": 1,
      "Netherlands": 1416,
      "New Zealand": 8,
      "Nicaragua": 0,
      "Niger": 0,
      "Nigeria": 2,
      "North Macedonia": 18,
      "Norway": 1333,
      "Oman": 22,
      "Pakistan": 136,
      "Panama": 55,
      "Papua New Guinea": 0,
      "Paraguay": 8,
      "Peru": 86,
      "Philippines": 142,
      "Poland": 177,
      "Portugal": 331,
      "Qatar": 439,
      "Romania": 158,
      "Russia": 90,
      "Rwanda": 5,
      "Saint Lucia": 2,
      "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines": 1,
      "San Marino": 109,
      "Saudi Arabia": 118,
      "Senegal": 24,
      "Serbia": 55,
      "Seychelles": 3,
      "Singapore": 243,
      "Slovakia": 63,
      "Slovenia": 253,
      "Somalia": 1,
      "South Africa": 62,
      "Spain": 9942,
      "Sri Lanka": 28,
      "Sudan": 1,
      "Suriname": 1,
      "Sweden": 1103,
      "Switzerland": 2200,
      "Taiwan*": 67,
      "Tanzania": 1,
      "Thailand": 147,
      "Togo": 1,
      "Trinidad and Tobago": 4,
      "Tunisia": 20,
      "Turkey": 18,
      "US": 4632,
      "Uganda": 0,
      "Ukraine": 7,
      "United Arab Emirates": 98,
      "United Kingdom": 1551,
      "Uruguay": 8,
      "Uzbekistan": 6,
      "Venezuela": 17,
      "Vietnam": 61,
      "Zambia": 0,
      "Zimbabwe": 0
    },
    "3/17/20": {
      "Afghanistan": 22,
      "Albania": 55,
      "Algeria": 60,
      "Andorra": 39,
      "Angola": 0,
      "Antigua and Barbuda": 1,
      "Argentina": 68,
      "Armenia": 78,
      "Australia": 452,
      "Austria": 1332,
      "Azerbaijan": 28,
      "Bahamas, The": 1,
      "Bahrain": 228,
      "Bangladesh": 10,
      "Barbados": 2,
      "Belarus": 36,
      "Belgium": 1243,
      "Benin": 1,
      "Bhutan": 1,
      "Bolivia": 11,
      "Bosnia and Herzegovina": 26,
      "Brazil": 321,
      "Brunei": 56,
      "Bulgaria": 67,
      "Burkina Faso": 15,
      "Cabo Verde": 0,
      "Cambodia": 33,
      "Cameroon": 10,
      "Canada": 478,
      "Cape Verde": 0,
      "Central African Republic": 1,
      "Chad": 0,
      "Chile": 201,
      "China": 81058,
      "Colombia": 65,
      "Congo (Brazzaville)": 1,
      "Congo (Kinshasa)": 3,
      "Costa Rica": 41,
      "Cote d'Ivoire": 5,
      "Croatia": 65,
      "Cruise Ship": 696,
      "Cuba": 5,
      "Cyprus": 46,
      "Czechia": 396,
      "Denmark": 1025,
      "Djibouti": 0,
      "Dominican Republic": 21,
      "East Timor": 0,
      "Ecuador": 58,
      "Egypt": 196,
      "El Salvador": 0,
      "Equatorial Guinea": 1,
      "Eritrea": 0,
      "Estonia": 225,
      "Eswatini": 1,
      "Ethiopia": 5,
      "Fiji": 0,
      "Finland": 321,
      "France": 7699,
      "Gabon": 1,
      "Gambia, The": 1,
      "Georgia": 34,
      "Germany": 9257,
      "Ghana": 7,
      "Greece": 387,
      "Guatemala": 6,
      "Guinea": 1,
      "Guyana": 7,
      "Haiti": 0,
      "Holy See": 1,
      "Honduras": 8,
      "Hungary": 50,
      "Iceland": 220,
      "India": 142,
      "Indonesia": 172,
      "Iran": 16169,
      "Iraq": 154,
      "Ireland": 223,
      "Israel": 337,
      "Italy": 31506,
      "Jamaica": 12,
      "Japan": 878,
      "Jordan": 34,
      "Kazakhstan": 33,
      "Kenya": 3,
      "Korea, South": 8320,
      "Kosovo": 2,
      "Kuwait": 130,
      "Kyrgyzstan": 0,
      "Latvia": 49,
      "Lebanon": 120,
      "Liberia": 1,
      "Liechtenstein": 7,
      "Lithuania": 25,
      "Luxembourg": 140,
      "Madagascar": 0,
      "Malaysia": 673,
      "Maldives": 13,
      "Malta": 38,
      "Martinique": 16,
      "Mauritania": 1,
      "Mauritius": 0,
      "Mexico": 82,
      "Moldova": 30,
      "Monaco": 7,
      "Mongolia": 5,
      "Montenegro": 2,
      "Morocco": 38,
      "Namibia": 2,
      "Nepal": 1,
      "Netherlands": 1711,
      "New Zealand": 12,
      "Nicaragua": 0,
      "Niger": 0,
      "Nigeria": 3,
      "North Macedonia": 26,
      "Norway": 1463,
      "Oman": 24,
      "Pakistan": 236,
      "Panama": 69,
      "Papua New Guinea": 0,
      "Paraguay": 9,
      "Peru": 117,
      "Philippines": 187,
      "Poland": 238,
      "Portugal": 448,
      "Qatar": 439,
      "Romania": 184,
      "Russia": 114,
      "Rwanda": 7,
      "Saint Lucia": 2,
      "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines": 1,
      "San Marino": 109,
      "Saudi Arabia": 171,
      "Senegal": 26,
      "Serbia": 65,
      "Seychelles": 4,
      "Singapore": 266,
      "Slovakia": 72,
      "Slovenia": 275,
      "Somalia": 1,
      "South Africa": 62,
      "Spain": 11748,
      "Sri Lanka": 44,
      "Sudan": 1,
      "Suriname": 1,
      "Sweden": 1190,
      "Switzerland": 2700,
      "Taiwan*": 77,
      "Tanzania": 1,
      "Thailand": 177,
      "Togo": 1,
      "Trinidad and Tobago": 5,
      "Tunisia": 24,
      "Turkey": 47,
      "US": 6421,
      "Uganda": 0,
      "Ukraine": 14,
      "United Arab Emirates": 98,
      "United Kingdom": 1960,
      "Uruguay": 29,
      "Uzbekistan": 10,
      "Venezuela": 33,
      "Vietnam": 66,
      "Zambia": 0,
      "Zimbabwe": 0
    },
    "3/18/20": {
      "Afghanistan": 22,
      "Albania": 59,
      "Algeria": 74,
      "Andorra": 39,
      "Angola": 0,
      "Antigua and Barbuda": 1,
      "Argentina": 79,
      "Armenia": 84,
      "Australia": 568,
      "Austria": 1646,
      "Azerbaijan": 28,
      "Bahamas, The": 1,
      "Bahrain": 256,
      "Bangladesh": 14,
      "Barbados": 2,
      "Belarus": 51,
      "Belgium": 1486,
      "Benin": 2,
      "Bhutan": 1,
      "Bolivia": 12,
      "Bosnia and Herzegovina": 38,
      "Brazil": 372,
      "Brunei": 68,
      "Bulgaria": 92,
      "Burkina Faso": 20,
      "Cabo Verde": 0,
      "Cambodia": 35,
      "Cameroon": 10,
      "Canada": 657,
      "Cape Verde": 0,
      "Central African Republic": 1,
      "Chad": 0,
      "Chile": 238,
      "China": 81102,
      "Colombia": 93,
      "Congo (Brazzaville)": 1,
      "Congo (Kinshasa)": 4,
      "Costa Rica": 50,
      "Cote d'Ivoire": 6,
      "Croatia": 81,
      "Cruise Ship": 712,
      "Cuba": 7,
      "Cyprus": 49,
      "Czechia": 464,
      "Denmark": 1116,
      "Djibouti": 1,
      "Dominican Republic": 21,
      "East Timor": 0,
      "Ecuador": 111,
      "Egypt": 196,
      "El Salvador": 0,
      "Equatorial Guinea": 4,
      "Eritrea": 0,
      "Estonia": 258,
      "Eswatini": 1,
      "Ethiopia": 6,
      "Fiji": 0,
      "Finland": 336,
      "France": 9105,
      "Gabon": 1,
      "Gambia, The": 1,
      "Georgia": 38,
      "Germany": 12327,
      "Ghana": 7,
      "Greece": 418,
      "Guatemala": 6,
      "Guinea": 1,
      "Guyana": 7,
      "Haiti": 0,
      "Holy See": 1,
      "Honduras": 9,
      "Hungary": 58,
      "Iceland": 250,
      "India": 156,
      "Indonesia": 227,
      "Iran": 17361,
      "Iraq": 164,
      "Ireland": 292,
      "Israel": 433,
      "Italy": 35713,
      "Jamaica": 13,
      "Japan": 889,
      "Jordan": 52,
      "Kazakhstan": 35,
      "Kenya": 3,
      "Korea, South": 8413,
      "Kosovo": 2,
      "Kuwait": 142,
      "Kyrgyzstan": 3,
      "Latvia": 71,
      "Lebanon": 133,
      "Liberia": 2,
      "Liechtenstein": 28,
      "Lithuania": 27,
      "Luxembourg": 203,
      "Madagascar": 0,
      "Malaysia": 790,
      "Maldives": 13,
      "Malta": 38,
      "Martinique": 19,
      "Mauritania": 1,
      "Mauritius": 3,
      "Mexico": 93,
      "Moldova": 30,
      "Monaco": 7,
      "Mongolia": 6,
      "Montenegro": 1,
      "Morocco": 49,
      "Namibia": 2,
      "Nepal": 1,
      "Netherlands": 2058,
      "New Zealand": 20,
      "Nicaragua": 0,
      "Niger": 0,
      "Nigeria": 8,
      "North Macedonia": 35,
      "Norway": 1550,
      "Oman": 39,
      "Pakistan": 299,
      "Panama": 86,
      "Papua New Guinea": 0,
      "Paraguay": 11,
      "Peru": 145,
      "Philippines": 202,
      "Poland": 251,
      "Portugal": 448,
      "Qatar": 452,
      "Romania": 260,
      "Russia": 147,
      "Rwanda": 8,
      "Saint Lucia": 2,
      "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines": 1,
      "San Marino": 119,
      "Saudi Arabia": 171,
      "Senegal": 31,
      "Serbia": 83,
      "Seychelles": 4,
      "Singapore": 313,
      "Slovakia": 105,
      "Slovenia": 275,
      "Somalia": 1,
      "South Africa": 116,
      "Spain": 13910,
      "Sri Lanka": 51,
      "Sudan": 2,
      "Suriname": 1,
      "Sweden": 1279,
      "Switzerland": 3028,
      "Taiwan*": 100,
      "Tanzania": 3,
      "Thailand": 212,
      "Togo": 1,
      "Trinidad and Tobago": 7,
      "Tunisia": 29,
      "Turkey": 98,
      "US": 7783,
      "Uganda": 0,
      "Ukraine": 14,
      "United Arab Emirates": 113,
      "United Kingdom": 2642,
      "Uruguay": 50,
      "Uzbekistan": 15,
      "Venezuela": 36,
      "Vietnam": 75,
      "Zambia": 2,
      "Zimbabwe": 0
    },
    "3/19/20": {
      "Afghanistan": 22,
      "Albania": 64,
      "Algeria": 87,
      "Andorra": 53,
      "Angola": 0,
      "Antigua and Barbuda": 1,
      "Argentina": 97,
      "Armenia": 115,
      "Australia": 681,
      "Austria": 2013,
      "Azerbaijan": 44,
      "Bahamas, The": 3,
      "Bahrain": 278,
      "Bangladesh": 17,
      "Barbados": 5,
      "Belarus": 51,
      "Belgium": 1795,
      "Benin": 2,
      "Bhutan": 1,
      "Bolivia": 12,
      "Bosnia and Herzegovina": 63,
      "Brazil": 621,
      "Brunei": 75,
      "Bulgaria": 94,
      "Burkina Faso": 33,
      "Cabo Verde": 0,
      "Cambodia": 37,
      "Cameroon": 13,
      "Canada": 800,
      "Cape Verde": 0,
      "Central African Republic": 1,
      "Chad": 1,
      "Chile": 238,
      "China": 81156,
      "Colombia": 102,
      "Congo (Brazzaville)": 3,
      "Congo (Kinshasa)": 14,
      "Costa Rica": 69,
      "Cote d'Ivoire": 9,
      "Croatia": 105,
      "Cruise Ship": 712,
      "Cuba": 11,
      "Cyprus": 67,
      "Czechia": 694,
      "Denmark": 1225,
      "Djibouti": 1,
      "Dominican Republic": 34,
      "East Timor": 0,
      "Ecuador": 199,
      "Egypt": 256,
      "El Salvador": 1,
      "Equatorial Guinea": 6,
      "Eritrea": 0,
      "Estonia": 267,
      "Eswatini": 1,
      "Ethiopia": 6,
      "Fiji": 1,
      "Finland": 400,
      "France": 10947,
      "Gabon": 1,
      "Gambia, The": 1,
      "Georgia": 40,
      "Germany": 15320,
      "Ghana": 11,
      "Greece": 418,
      "Guatemala": 9,
      "Guinea": 1,
      "Guyana": 7,
      "Haiti": 0,
      "Holy See": 1,
      "Honduras": 12,
      "Hungary": 73,
      "Iceland": 330,
      "India": 194,
      "Indonesia": 311,
      "Iran": 18407,
      "Iraq": 192,
      "Ireland": 557,
      "Israel": 677,
      "Italy": 41035,
      "Jamaica": 15,
      "Japan": 924,
      "Jordan": 69,
      "Kazakhstan": 44,
      "Kenya": 7,
      "Korea, South": 8565,
      "Kosovo": 2,
      "Kuwait": 148,
      "Kyrgyzstan": 3,
      "Latvia": 86,
      "Lebanon": 157,
      "Liberia": 2,
      "Liechtenstein": 28,
      "Lithuania": 36,
      "Luxembourg": 335,
      "Madagascar": 0,
      "Malaysia": 900,
      "Maldives": 13,
      "Malta": 53,
      "Martinique": 23,
      "Mauritania": 2,
      "Mauritius": 3,
      "Mexico": 118,
      "Moldova": 49,
      "Monaco": 7,
      "Mongolia": 6,
      "Montenegro": 3,
      "Morocco": 63,
      "Namibia": 3,
      "Nepal": 1,
      "Netherlands": 2467,
      "New Zealand": 28,
      "Nicaragua": 1,
      "Niger": 0,
      "Nigeria": 8,
      "North Macedonia": 48,
      "Norway": 1746,
      "Oman": 48,
      "Pakistan": 454,
      "Panama": 109,
      "Papua New Guinea": 0,
      "Paraguay": 11,
      "Peru": 234,
      "Philippines": 217,
      "Poland": 355,
      "Portugal": 785,
      "Qatar": 460,
      "Romania": 277,
      "Russia": 199,
      "Rwanda": 8,
      "Saint Lucia": 2,
      "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines": 1,
      "San Marino": 119,
      "Saudi Arabia": 274,
      "Senegal": 31,
      "Serbia": 103,
      "Seychelles": 6,
      "Singapore": 345,
      "Slovakia": 123,
      "Slovenia": 286,
      "Somalia": 1,
      "South Africa": 150,
      "Spain": 17963,
      "Sri Lanka": 60,
      "Sudan": 2,
      "Suriname": 1,
      "Sweden": 1439,
      "Switzerland": 4075,
      "Taiwan*": 108,
      "Tanzania": 6,
      "Thailand": 272,
      "Togo": 1,
      "Trinidad and Tobago": 9,
      "Tunisia": 39,
      "Turkey": 192,
      "US": 13677,
      "Uganda": 0,
      "Ukraine": 16,
      "United Arab Emirates": 140,
      "United Kingdom": 2716,
      "Uruguay": 79,
      "Uzbekistan": 23,
      "Venezuela": 42,
      "Vietnam": 85,
      "Zambia": 2,
      "Zimbabwe": 0
    },
    "3/20/20": {
      "Afghanistan": 24,
      "Albania": 70,
      "Algeria": 90,
      "Andorra": 75,
      "Angola": 1,
      "Antigua and Barbuda": 1,
      "Argentina": 128,
      "Armenia": 136,
      "Australia": 791,
      "Austria": 2388,
      "Azerbaijan": 44,
      "Bahamas, The": 3,
      "Bahrain": 285,
      "Bangladesh": 20,
      "Barbados": 5,
      "Belarus": 69,
      "Belgium": 2257,
      "Benin": 2,
      "Bhutan": 2,
      "Bolivia": 15,
      "Bosnia and Herzegovina": 89,
      "Brazil": 793,
      "Brunei": 78,
      "Bulgaria": 127,
      "Burkina Faso": 40,
      "Cabo Verde": 1,
      "Cambodia": 51,
      "Cameroon": 20,
      "Canada": 943,
      "Cape Verde": 0,
      "Central African Republic": 3,
      "Chad": 1,
      "Chile": 434,
      "China": 81250,
      "Colombia": 128,
      "Congo (Brazzaville)": 3,
      "Congo (Kinshasa)": 18,
      "Costa Rica": 89,
      "Cote d'Ivoire": 9,
      "Croatia": 128,
      "Cruise Ship": 712,
      "Cuba": 16,
      "Cyprus": 67,
      "Czechia": 833,
      "Denmark": 1337,
      "Djibouti": 1,
      "Dominican Republic": 72,
      "East Timor": 0,
      "Ecuador": 367,
      "Egypt": 285,
      "El Salvador": 1,
      "Equatorial Guinea": 6,
      "Eritrea": 0,
      "Estonia": 283,
      "Eswatini": 1,
      "Ethiopia": 9,
      "Fiji": 1,
      "Finland": 450,
      "France": 12726,
      "Gabon": 3,
      "Gambia, The": 1,
      "Georgia": 43,
      "Germany": 19848,
      "Ghana": 16,
      "Greece": 495,
      "Guatemala": 12,
      "Guinea": 1,
      "Guyana": 7,
      "Haiti": 2,
      "Holy See": 1,
      "Honduras": 24,
      "Hungary": 85,
      "Iceland": 409,
      "India": 244,
      "Indonesia": 369,
      "Iran": 19644,
      "Iraq": 208,
      "Ireland": 683,
      "Israel": 705,
      "Italy": 47021,
      "Jamaica": 16,
      "Japan": 963,
      "Jordan": 85,
      "Kazakhstan": 49,
      "Kenya": 7,
      "Korea, South": 8652,
      "Kosovo": 2,
      "Kuwait": 159,
      "Kyrgyzstan": 6,
      "Latvia": 111,
      "Lebanon": 163,
      "Liberia": 2,
      "Liechtenstein": 28,
      "Lithuania": 49,
      "Luxembourg": 484,
      "Madagascar": 3,
      "Malaysia": 1030,
      "Maldives": 13,
      "Malta": 64,
      "Martinique": 32,
      "Mauritania": 2,
      "Mauritius": 12,
      "Mexico": 164,
      "Moldova": 66,
      "Monaco": 11,
      "Mongolia": 6,
      "Montenegro": 14,
      "Morocco": 77,
      "Namibia": 3,
      "Nepal": 1,
      "Netherlands": 3003,
      "New Zealand": 39,
      "Nicaragua": 1,
      "Niger": 1,
      "Nigeria": 12,
      "North Macedonia": 67,
      "Norway": 1914,
      "Oman": 48,
      "Pakistan": 501,
      "Panama": 137,
      "Papua New Guinea": 1,
      "Paraguay": 13,
      "Peru": 234,
      "Philippines": 230,
      "Poland": 425,
      "Portugal": 1020,
      "Qatar": 470,
      "Romania": 308,
      "Russia": 253,
      "Rwanda": 17,
      "Saint Lucia": 2,
      "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines": 1,
      "San Marino": 144,
      "Saudi Arabia": 344,
      "Senegal": 38,
      "Serbia": 135,
      "Seychelles": 7,
      "Singapore": 385,
      "Slovakia": 137,
      "Slovenia": 341,
      "Somalia": 1,
      "South Africa": 202,
      "Spain": 20410,
      "Sri Lanka": 73,
      "Sudan": 2,
      "Suriname": 4,
      "Sweden": 1639,
      "Switzerland": 5294,
      "Taiwan*": 135,
      "Tanzania": 6,
      "Thailand": 322,
      "Togo": 9,
      "Trinidad and Tobago": 9,
      "Tunisia": 54,
      "Turkey": 359,
      "US": 19100,
      "Uganda": 0,
      "Ukraine": 29,
      "United Arab Emirates": 140,
      "United Kingdom": 4014,
      "Uruguay": 94,
      "Uzbekistan": 33,
      "Venezuela": 42,
      "Vietnam": 91,
      "Zambia": 2,
      "Zimbabwe": 1
    },
    "3/21/20": {
      "Afghanistan": 24,
      "Albania": 76,
      "Algeria": 139,
      "Andorra": 88,
      "Angola": 2,
      "Antigua and Barbuda": 1,
      "Argentina": 158,
      "Armenia": 160,
      "Australia": 1071,
      "Austria": 2814,
      "Azerbaijan": 53,
      "Bahamas, The": 4,
      "Bahrain": 305,
      "Bangladesh": 25,
      "Barbados": 6,
      "Belarus": 76,
      "Belgium": 2815,
      "Benin": 2,
      "Bhutan": 2,
      "Bolivia": 19,
      "Bosnia and Herzegovina": 93,
      "Brazil": 1021,
      "Brunei": 83,
      "Bulgaria": 163,
      "Burkina Faso": 64,
      "Cabo Verde": 3,
      "Cambodia": 53,
      "Cameroon": 27,
      "Canada": 1278,
      "Cape Verde": 1,
      "Central African Republic": 3,
      "Chad": 1,
      "Chile": 537,
      "China": 81305,
      "Colombia": 196,
      "Congo (Brazzaville)": 3,
      "Congo (Kinshasa)": 23,
      "Costa Rica": 117,
      "Cote d'Ivoire": 14,
      "Croatia": 206,
      "Cruise Ship": 712,
      "Cuba": 21,
      "Cyprus": 84,
      "Czechia": 995,
      "Denmark": 1420,
      "Djibouti": 1,
      "Dominican Republic": 112,
      "East Timor": 1,
      "Ecuador": 506,
      "Egypt": 294,
      "El Salvador": 3,
      "Equatorial Guinea": 6,
      "Eritrea": 1,
      "Estonia": 306,
      "Eswatini": 1,
      "Ethiopia": 9,
      "Fiji": 1,
      "Finland": 523,
      "France": 14431,
      "Gabon": 4,
      "Gambia, The": 1,
      "Georgia": 49,
      "Germany": 22213,
      "Ghana": 19,
      "Greece": 530,
      "Guatemala": 17,
      "Guinea": 2,
      "Guyana": 7,
      "Haiti": 2,
      "Holy See": 1,
      "Honduras": 24,
      "Hungary": 103,
      "Iceland": 473,
      "India": 330,
      "Indonesia": 450,
      "Iran": 20610,
      "Iraq": 214,
      "Ireland": 785,
      "Israel": 883,
      "Italy": 53578,
      "Jamaica": 16,
      "Japan": 1007,
      "Jordan": 85,
      "Kazakhstan": 53,
      "Kenya": 7,
      "Korea, South": 8799,
      "Kosovo": 2,
      "Kuwait": 176,
      "Kyrgyzstan": 14,
      "Latvia": 124,
      "Lebanon": 187,
      "Liberia": 3,
      "Liechtenstein": 37,
      "Lithuania": 83,
      "Luxembourg": 670,
      "Madagascar": 3,
      "Malaysia": 1183,
      "Maldives": 13,
      "Malta": 73,
      "Martinique": 32,
      "Mauritania": 2,
      "Mauritius": 14,
      "Mexico": 203,
      "Moldova": 80,
      "Monaco": 11,
      "Mongolia": 10,
      "Montenegro": 14,
      "Morocco": 96,
      "Namibia": 3,
      "Nepal": 1,
      "Netherlands": 3640,
      "New Zealand": 52,
      "Nicaragua": 2,
      "Niger": 1,
      "Nigeria": 22,
      "North Macedonia": 85,
      "Norway": 2118,
      "Oman": 52,
      "Pakistan": 730,
      "Panama": 200,
      "Papua New Guinea": 1,
      "Paraguay": 18,
      "Peru": 318,
      "Philippines": 307,
      "Poland": 536,
      "Portugal": 1280,
      "Qatar": 481,
      "Romania": 367,
      "Russia": 306,
      "Rwanda": 17,
      "Saint Lucia": 2,
      "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines": 1,
      "San Marino": 144,
      "Saudi Arabia": 392,
      "Senegal": 47,
      "Serbia": 171,
      "Seychelles": 7,
      "Singapore": 432,
      "Slovakia": 178,
      "Slovenia": 383,
      "Somalia": 1,
      "South Africa": 240,
      "Spain": 25374,
      "Sri Lanka": 77,
      "Sudan": 2,
      "Suriname": 4,
      "Sweden": 1763,
      "Switzerland": 6575,
      "Taiwan*": 153,
      "Tanzania": 6,
      "Thailand": 411,
      "Togo": 16,
      "Trinidad and Tobago": 49,
      "Tunisia": 60,
      "Turkey": 670,
      "US": 25489,
      "Uganda": 1,
      "Ukraine": 47,
      "United Arab Emirates": 153,
      "United Kingdom": 5067,
      "Uruguay": 110,
      "Uzbekistan": 43,
      "Venezuela": 70,
      "Vietnam": 94,
      "Zambia": 2,
      "Zimbabwe": 3
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible for it to return an object where it shows how many days it took for the number of cases in each country to **double** ?

Comment: Beautiful topic.

Comment: I wonder what this could be about...?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Should be a simple 2 for loop. Did you try anything?

Comment: I'm very new to working with objects in javascript, this is all out of interest. It would be helpful if I get some direction on what should I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain the `initial count` of infected people country wise and then iterate over the countries and check if the count is `double` of initial count.

```
// Store number of days
let days = 0;

const countriesWithDoubleDayCount = {};
const dates = Object.keys(data.data);
const countries = Object.values(data.data);

// Create any Object of countries with count set to zero
const groupByCountries = Object.keys(data.data["3/15/20"]).reduce((accu, name) => {
    accu[name] = 0;
    return accu;
}, {});

const initialCountCountryWise = {};

const doubleCount = countries.reduce((a, country, i) => {
    if (i < dates.length - 1) {
        // Date Difference Calculation
        days += Math.abs((new Date(dates[i + 1]) - new Date(dates[i])) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24), 10);
    }

    const countries = Object.entries(country);

    countries.forEach(([name, count]) => {
        // First Record 
        if (i == 0) {
            // Maintain the initial count of coronavirus infected people, country wise.
            initialCountCountryWise[name] = count !== 0 ? count : 1;
        }

        a[name] = count;
        const double = initialCountCountryWise[name] * 2;

        // Check if current country count is greater than double of initial count
        // If yes, push in the countriesWithDoubleDayCount Object.
        if (a[name] >= double && !countriesWithDoubleDayCount.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            countriesWithDoubleDayCount[name] = days;
        }
    });

    return a;
}, groupByCountries);

console.log(countriesWithDoubleDayCount);
```

**Note** - Due to character limit cannot add `Javascript live code snippet`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm starting to get interested in coding now.